# Having errors running JigLibX 0.3.1 on XNA 4.0

Tags: xna-4.0

**Warning  1:**

> The referenced assembly "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline, 
>   Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" 
>   could not be resolved because it has a dependency on
>   "Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently
>   targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please
>   remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or
>   consider retargeting your project.    JigLibX

**Warning   2:**

> The referenced assembly "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553"
>   could not be resolved because it has a dependency on
>   "Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently
>   targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please
>   remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or
>   consider retargeting your project.    JigLibX

**Error 3:**

```
Error loading pipeline assembly "HeightmapProcessor, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".  JigLibGame
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your assembly (you didn't give details - is it an application? a game? a library? a content pipeline extension?) is depending on the XNA content pipeline assemblies, which themselves require the full .NET 4 framework -- currently you are targeting the .NET 4 Client Profile framework.

You need to do exactly what the exception says:

You could remove the assembly references to the content pipeline assemblies, if that is possible.

Or you could change the target framework. To do this, right click your project in the Solution Explorer, select Properties, on the Application tab find the Target framework drop-down and change from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 4"

It is worth pointing out that the XNA content pipeline assemblies are not redistributable: you cannot include them with your game.